# How to define intersection between two domains like cylinders

Tags: python, modeling, scripting

I am very new to Blender and am working with modeling a few cylinders using **Python**. I am able to model them, but I also want to be able to select only those cylinders that are not intersecting with any previously modeled cylinders. To do this, I need to define the *intersection between two domains*. Thanks for any help.

Additionally, here is the current script that I am using to generate a number of cylinders:

```
 import bpy
 from bpy import context
 from mathutils import *; from math
 import *
 import random
```

When editing, use a fixed value (10). Eventually, make the number user adjustable.

Add 'total' objects (10) into the scene

```
for i in range(total):

    a=random.randint(2,20)
    b=random.randint(2,20)
    c=random.randint(2,20)
    add_cyl=bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius = 1, depth = 5, location=(a,b,c))
```

Comment: @ShadyPuck Careful when editing code, see the edit history to see what I changed on your edit: http://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/53191/revisions